# Image of isometric immersion

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M$ a metric space with the following property: For all isometric immersion $f:M\to N$, the image of $f(M)$ is a open set in $N$. Prove that $M$ is empty set.

A function $f:M\to N$, is called "isometric immersion", when $d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)$, for all $x,y\in M$, and also, the isometric immersion is always injective. And finally the "isometry", is a "isometric immersion" that is sobrejective.

Comment: If $d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)$ then $f$ is automatically injective.

Comment: Yes, I know. I only mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I$ be the unit interval and consider $X = M \times I$ equipped with the metric defined by $d_X((t, x), (u, y)) = \sqrt{d_M(t, u)^2 + |x - y|^2}$. Then $t \mapsto (t, 0)$ is an isometric immersion of $M$ into $X$  whose image can only be open if $M = X = \emptyset$.

Comment: I don't understand, why $t\to (t,0)$ is an isometric immersion??

Comment: @Ahna: Compute $d_X((t,0),(u,0))$.

Comment: Look at the definition I gave for $d_X$ and think  about what it says when $x = y = 0$.

Comment: Note that the only important property of I used here is that it contains a point which is not isolated. So any non-discrete metric space could be used in its place.

Comment: @RobArthan Apologizes for this question, but because you thought in define $X=M\times I$, and this metric??